# The files for this update have not yet downloaded

Tags: wsus

I have several disconnected WSUS servers on different domains.  All of them work fine except the most recent one I stood up.  I follow the same procedures that work perfectly for all my other systems and this one, after importing the metadata and approving the updates all but a few of the updates are labeled with the notepad icon and say "the files for this update have not yet downloaded".  They appear to still be getting pushed out to the servers on the domain though, I just don't understand why they are labeled this way in WSUS.

I downloaded the updates from a connected WSUS server and placed them on the disconnected server and I do this several times a week and there are no problems on my other systems so I know I'm doing the import/export process correctly.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!